# Gulp Source doesn't copy the correct name

Tags: angular, gulp, node-modules, angular2-seed

I'm using the angular 2 seed with a spring-boot backend and need to copy my node_modules files into the resources folder so that it's visible to my java code. I wrote this script:

```
   export = () => {
  gulp.src(gnf(), {base:'./'}).pipe(gulp.dest(Config.DEV_DEST));
  gulp.src('node_modules/.tmp/**/*', {base:'./'}).pipe(gulp.dest(Config.DEV_DEST));

};
```

The problem that I'm running into is that the line:

```
gulp.src('node_modules/.tmp/**/*', {base:'./'}).pipe(gulp.dest(Config.DEV_DEST));
```

copies the .tmp folder as just tmp. Is there an easy way to specify that I want to copy the folder as .tmp?

Comment: `gulp-rename` should do the job: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/34

Comment: It looks like that renames a file and not a folder unfortunately